# Why is my splay tree not saving any values?

Tags: c++, tree

I am just looking for an explanation as to why my tester is saying that my nodes are not being saved. The tester says that inserting is fine, and it tests to see if they are properly lined up. But when it goes back to count the nodes it's saying that only two of them are linked. I've provided what the output is and my code below. I think there is a problem with my rotate function but when I drew a diagram and went step by step it seemed fine. Is it possible that my splay function is wrong? The "Testing tree insertion..." thinks that it's fine so I don't know what to do.

```
---- Beginning tree tests ----
Testing tree insertion...21 23 27 38 32 33 16 11 26 8 15 6 30 13 0 40 20 3 9 34 14 17 37 18 28 24 2 10 7 35 19 29 25 22 36 39 1 4 12 31 5
FAILED: tree does not have the correct number of nodes. (expected 41, found 2)
--- Tree structure ---
  5
 ├─ 31 [p = 5]
 └─(null)




/*
 * assign4_test.cc
 * Assignment 4 (BST) test runner.
 */
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using std::cout;

std::vector<unsigned> make_random_permutation(
    std::size_t len,
    int seed = 1) 
{
    std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
    std::vector<unsigned> ret(len, 0);

    // Initialize vector to 0...len-1
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
        ret.at(i) = i;

    std::shuffle(ret.begin(), ret.end(), generator);

    return ret;

}

// Node structure
struct node {
    int key;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node* parent;
};

/* 
 * User-implemented functions
 */
void rotate(node* child, node* parent);     // Rotation
bool find(node*& root, int value);          // Search
node* insert(node* root, int value);        // Insertion
node* insertRec(node*root, int value);
//node* remove(node* root, int value);      // Deletion
node* splay(node* t);                       // Splay

void rotate(node* child, node* parent){
    if(parent->left == child){
        child->parent = parent->parent;
        if(parent->parent != nullptr){
            if(child->key < parent->parent->key){
                parent->parent->left = child;
            }
            else
                parent->parent->right = child;
        }
        parent->parent = child;
        parent->left = child->right;
        if(child->right != nullptr)
            child->right->parent = parent;
        child->right = parent;
    }   
    else{
        child->parent = parent->parent;
        if(parent->parent != nullptr){
            if(child->key < parent->parent->key){
                parent->parent->left = child;
        }
            else
                parent->parent->right = child;
        }
        parent->parent = child;
        parent->right = child->left;
        if(child->left != nullptr)
            child->left->parent = parent;
        child->left = parent;
    }
}

node* insertRec(node* root, int value){
    node* newNode = new node();
    newNode->key = value;
    if(root == nullptr)
        return newNode;
    else if(value < root->key){
        root->left = insertRec(root->left, value);
        root->left->parent = root;
    }
    else{
        root->right = insertRec(root->right, value);
        root->right->parent = root;
    }
}

node* insert(node* root, int value){
    root = splay(insertRec(root,value));
    return root;

}

bool find(node*& root, int value){
    node* temp = root;
    if(temp == nullptr)
        return false;
    else if(temp->key == value){
        root = splay(temp);
        return true;
    }
    else if(value > temp->key)
        return find(temp->right, value);
    else
        return find(temp->left, value);
}

node* splay(node* t){
    while(t->parent != nullptr){
        if(t->parent->parent == nullptr)
            rotate(t, t->parent);
        else{
            rotate(t,t->parent);
            rotate(t,t->parent);
        }
    }
    return t;
}
/******************************************************************************
 Tree structure checking
 ******************************************************************************/

// Balance measurement, returns a balance factor between 0 (not possible) and 1
// (perfectly balanced).
float balance(node* root) {
    if(!root)
        return 1.0; // Empty tree is perfectly balanced
    else if(!root->left) {
        // One subtree, on the right
        return 0.5 * balance(root->left);        
    }
    else if(!root->right) {
        return 0.5 * balance(root->right);
    }
    else // Two subtrees
        return (balance(root->right) + balance(root->left)) / 2;
}

// Safe find, that does not modify the tree structure
bool safe_find(node* root, int value) {
    if(!root)
        return false;
    else if(root->key == value)
        return true;
    else if(value < root->key)
        return safe_find(root->left, value);
    else // value < root->key
        return safe_find(root->right, value);
}

int count_nodes(node* root) {
    if(!root)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + count_nodes(root->left) + count_nodes(root->right);
}

int tree_height(node* root) {
    if(!root)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + std::max(tree_height(root->left), tree_height(root->right));
}

// Pretty-print a tree. This does cycle-checking at the same time, so that if
// there's a cycle in the tree we won't get stuck in a loop.
void print(node* root, int level, int parents, bool left_child, std::set<node*>& nodes) {

    if(level == 0)
        cout << "--- Tree structure ---\n";

    // Print indent for node
    for(int i = 0; i < level-1; ++i)
        if(parents & (1 << i))
            cout << " â”‚ ";
        else 
            cout << "   ";

    if(level > 0)
        cout << (left_child ? " â”œâ”€" : " â””â”€");

    if(root == nullptr) {
        cout << "(null)" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(nodes.count(root) > 0) {
        // Already printed this node somewhere else
        cout << "CYCLE (" << root->key << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        nodes.insert(root); // Visit root

        // Print children
        cout.width(3);
        cout << root->key; 
        if(root->parent != nullptr)
            cout << " [p = " << root->parent->key << "]";
        cout << std::endl;

        // Print children
        if(root->left || root->right) {
            // We only print both children if one of them is non-null.
            // If both are null we don't print anything, to avoid making a huge
            // mess.

            // We print the children in the order right, left so that you can
            // turn your head (or your screen) to the left and the tree will
            // be correct.
            print(root->right, level+1, parents | (1 << level), true, nodes);
            print(root->left, level+1, parents, false, nodes);
        }
    }
}

void print(node* root) {
    std::set<node*> nodes;

    print(root, 0, 0, true, nodes);    
}


/* check_for_cycles(n)
   Traverse the tree (preorder) starting at n, checking for cycles of nodes.
   Note that this does not check for parent-pointer cycles, only child-pointer
   cycles.
*/
bool check_for_cycles(node* n, std::set<node*>& nodes) {
    if(nodes.count(n) > 0)
        return false;
    else {
        nodes.insert(n); // Mark n as seen

        // Explore left and right subtrees
        bool ret = true;
        if(n->left)
            ret = ret && check_for_cycles(n->left, nodes);
        if(n->right)
            ret = ret && check_for_cycles(n->right, nodes);

        return ret;
    }
}

bool check_for_cycles(node* n) {
    std::set<node*> nodes;

    if(!check_for_cycles(n, nodes)) {
        cout << "FAILED: tree structure contains a cycle.\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

// Check the pointer structure of the tree (parent/child) to make sure it is
// correct. 
bool check_tree_pointers(node* root, bool is_root = true) {
    if(!root)
        return true;
    else {
        if(is_root && root->parent != nullptr) {
            cout << "FAILED: root->parent should always be null.\n";
            return false;            
        }

        // Child child nodes (if they exist) to make sure their parents
        // point back to root.
        if(root->left) {
            if(root->left->parent != root) {
                cout << "FAILED: found node " << root->left->key 
                     << " with incorrect parent pointer.\n";
                return false;
            }
            if(root->left->key >= root->key) {
                cout << "FAILED: found node " << root->left->key
                     << " which is on the wrong side of parent.\n";
                return false;
            }
        }

        if(root->right) {
            if(root->right->parent != root) {
                cout << "FAILED: found node " << root->right->key 
                     << " with incorrect parent pointer.\n";
                return false;
            }
            if(root->right->key <= root->key) {
                cout << "FAILED: found node " << root->right->key
                     << " which is on the wrong side of parent.\n";
                return false;
            }            
        }

        if(root->right && root->left) {
            // Both children, if they exist, have valid parent pointers.
            // So now we check both subtrees recursively.
            return check_tree_pointers(root->left,  false) && 
                   check_tree_pointers(root->right, false);
        }

        return true;
    }
}

bool check_tree_values(node* root, 
                       int low = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
                       int high = std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) {
    if(!root)
        return true;
    else if(root->key <= low) {
        cout << "FAILED: found node " << root->key << " improperly placed.\n";
        return false;
    }
    else if(root->key >= high) {
        cout << "FAILED: found node " << root->key << " improperly placed.\n";
        return false;   
    }
    else { // root->key is in the correct range
        return check_tree_values(root->left, low, root->key) &&
               check_tree_values(root->right, root->key, high);
    }

}

bool check_tree(node* root) {
    if(root->parent != nullptr) {
        cout << "FAILED: Root of tree must have null parent pointer";
        cout << " (root->parent->key = " << root->parent->key << ")\n";
        return false;
    }

    return check_for_cycles(root) && 
           check_tree_pointers(root) && 
           check_tree_values(root);    
}

/******************************************************************************
 Tree testing
 ******************************************************************************/

template<typename Func>
struct scope_exit {
    scope_exit(Func f) : exit(f)
    {}

    ~scope_exit() {
        exit();
    }

    Func exit;
};

template<typename Func>
scope_exit<Func> make_scope_exit(Func f) {
    return scope_exit<Func>(f);
}

// To test the tree functions, we generate a random permutation of the integers
// from -20 to 20 and insert them into the tree. Then, we generate another
// permutation and find them in that order. Finally, we generate another
// permutation and remove them in that order. After every operation, we perform
// a full check of the tree structure. The test stops if the tree structure is
// not valid at any point.

bool test_rotate() {

    // This is a huge mess. I need to come up with a better way to test
    // left/right rotations. Maybe use member-pointers to abstract over
    // the orientation?

    // Root of the pseudo-tree
    node* root = new node{10000, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};
    /* Left-rotation tree:
           p   
          / \   
         c   Z  
        / \  
       X   Y
    */
    node* X = new node{-10, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};
    node* Y = new node{-20, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};
    node* Z = new node{-30, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};    
    node* child = new node{2, X, Y, nullptr};
    node* parent = new node{1, child, Z, root};

    // This is to avoid memory leaks: the function will be called when this
    // function returns. 
    auto exiter = make_scope_exit([&]() { 
        delete X;
        delete Y;
        delete Z;
        delete child;
        delete parent;
    });

    child->parent = parent;
    X->parent = Y->parent = child;
    Z->parent = parent;

    rotate(child, parent);
    /* New structure should be
            c
           / \ 
          X   p
             / \ 
            Y   Z
    */
    if(child->parent != root) {
        cout << "FAILED: parent's parent is not preserved.\n";
        return false;
    }
    if(child->right != parent) {
        cout << "FAILED: rotate did not make parent into child.\n";
        return false;
    }
    if(child->left != X) {
        cout << "FAILED: left child of child should be unchanged\n";
        return false;

    } else if(parent->left != Y) {
        cout << "FAILED: child's right child should become right-child of parent.\n";
        return false;
    } else if(parent->right != Z) {
        cout << "FAILED: right child of parent should be unchanged.\n";
        return false;
    }
    else if(parent->parent != child) {
        cout << "FAILED: parent->parent is not original child.\n";
        return false;
    }    
    else if(!check_for_cycles(child)) {
        cout << "FAILED: rotation created a cycle\n";
        print(child);
        return false;
    }

    // Right-rotation
    delete child; delete parent;
    child = new node{2, Y, Z, nullptr};
    parent = new node{1, X, child, root};
    child->parent = parent;
    X->parent = parent;
    Y->parent = Z->parent = child;
    rotate(child, parent);

    if(child->parent != root) {
        cout << "FAILED: parent's parent is not preserved.\n";
        return false;
    }
    if(child->left != parent) {
        cout << "FAILED: rotate did not make parent into child.\n";
        return false;
    }
    if(parent->left != X) {
        cout << "FAILED: left child of parent should be unchanged.\n";
        return false;
    }
    else if(child->right != Z) {
        cout << "FAILED: right child of child should be unchanged.\n";
        return false;
    } 
    else if(parent->right != Y) {
        cout << "FAILED: left child of child should become right child of parent\n";
        return false;
    }
    else if(parent->parent != child) {
        cout << "FAILED: parent->parent is not original child.\n";
        return false;
    }
    else if(!check_for_cycles(child)) {
        cout << "FAILED: rotation created a cycle\n";
        print(child);
        return false;
    }

    // Do a quick test with null children and null root
    // If the user made a mistake here, this will most likely segfault.
    delete child;
    delete parent;
    child = new node{1, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};
    parent = new node{0, child, nullptr, nullptr};
    child->parent = parent;
    rotate(child, parent);
    if(parent->parent != child) {
        cout << "FAILED: parent did not become the child\n";
        return false;
    }
    else if(child->right != parent) {
        cout << "FAILED: parent did not become right child\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool test_tree() {
    node* t = nullptr; // Empty tree

    // Generate test data
    std::vector<unsigned> test = make_random_permutation(41, 12);

    // Insert a random permutation
    cout << "Testing tree insertion...";
    for(unsigned u : test) {
        const int i = static_cast<int>(u);
        cout << u << " ";

        t = insert(t, i);
        if(!check_tree(t)) {
            print(t);
            return false; // Stop if the check fails.
        }

        if(t->key != i) {
            cout << "FAILED: After inserting " << i << " it should be splayed to the root\n";
            print(t);
            return false;
        } 

    }
    cout << std::endl;

    int cn = count_nodes(t);
    if(cn != 41) {
        cout << "FAILED: tree does not have the correct number of nodes. ";
        cout << "(expected 41, found " << cn << ")\n";
        print(t);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        cout << "OK so far...\n";
        print(t);
    }

    // Find a random permutation
    cout << "Testing tree find()...";
    for(unsigned u : test) {
        const int i = static_cast<int>(u);  
        cout << i << " ";

        if(!find(t, i)) {
            cout << "FAILED: find() couldn't find " << i << "\n";
            return false;
        }

        if(t->key != i) {
            cout << "FAILED: find() did not splay target to the root.\n";
            print(t);
            return false;
        }

        if(!check_tree(t)) {
            print(t);
            return false;
        }        
    }
    cout << std::endl;
    print(t);

    // We no longer test removal, because students are not required to implement
    // remove(). It's too fiddly to get right, too many edge cases.
    /*
    // Remove a random permutation
    cout << "Testing tree removal...\n";
    for(unsigned u : test) {
        const int i = static_cast<int>(u);

        t = remove(t, i);

        if(!check_tree(t)) {
            print(t);
            return false;
        }
        if(safe_find(t,i)) {
            cout << "FAILED: removed element " << i << " is still present in the tree\n";
            print(t);
            return false;
        }        
    }

    if(t != nullptr) {
        cout << "FAILED: Tree not empty after removing all elements.\n";    
        print(t);
        return false;
    }
    */

    return true;
}

int main() {
    cout << "---- Beginning tree tests ----\n";
    if(test_rotate() && test_tree()) 
        cout << "---- All tests successful ----\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is clearly not C.

Comment: You need to return values from `insertRec`. Crank up the warnings on your compiler.

Comment: @molbdnilo what do you mean by I need to return values? I thought the function would return a value no matter what because it would eventually reach a point where root would be a nullptr.

Comment: @JasonPham -- Did your compiler warn you about all control path's are not returning a value?  What did you do about it, or are you hoping that the return isn't needed?  Exiting a function that is supposed to return a value without returning a value is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did get the warning but I assumed that it will always work since no values are repeated. Do I need to make it return a value? Is that the problem I was having?

Comment: @straightson -- Please look at [this example](https://www.ideone.com/uskFjH).  See the message `Testing tree insertion...21 23 Behavior is now undefined` in the output at the bottom?  This proves your assumptions were wrong.  You are returning from a function without specifying a return, thus all bets are off as to what to expect.  Second, why are you not using a debugger?  There is no way you could write all of this code, and expect it to work on the first or second try.  Learn to use the debugger that is part of your compiler toolset.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can't use a debugger because I don't know if I have one. I am using the putty to connect to my school's server and they don't do a good job of explaining to a novice how to use it. I only know how to use a text editor and the compiler. That aside, I managed to fix the issue I think. I am not getting an error where a node was not properly placed so I think that was to do with my splay function. Any tips?

Comment: @straightson -- To solve your problem, guess what tool we would have to use?  That's right -- the debugger.  No one is going to be able to run that entire program you posted in their head.  So it makes it worth your while to figure out how to use the debugger in your environment, or make demands to your teacher(s) on how to debug your programs in your environment.  Second, if you are still not returning a value, your problem isn't really fixed, since your program may fail to run correctly when run on another system, different compiler, compiler options, etc.

Comment: @straightson There's no "eventually", a recursive function works exactly like all other functions and must return something on every path. (The big secret of recursion is that there's nothing special about it.) That you got this right in all the other recursive functions makes it look like you copied those from someone without understanding them.

Comment: @molbdnilo The only recursive function I wrote was the insertRec function. Everything else was provided by my instructor to be used as a tester